# How to deploy a Flutter Web App in a Second Firebase Hosting?

Tags: flutter-web, firebase-hosting

Inside a Firebase project called `originalawesome` I set up a second site on Firebase Hosting, then I have:

```
originalawesome.web.app
secondawesome.web.app
```

The first one (`originalawesome`) has a JS application in production.

In the second (`secondawesome`) I want to install a Flutter Web App and for this I am following the following steps:

```
firebase init
(I select Hosting)
(I select to use an existing project)
(I select the project - originalawesome) //secondawesome is not an option
```

There it asks me to select the directory to publish, so I suppose the Flutter Web application will publish on my site in production, which is wrong.

Reading the documentation in [Share project resources across multiple sites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites) , when deployments are to be made in different sites, the `Deploy Targets` are requested to be differential with the following command:

```
firebase target: apply hosting secondawesome secondawesome
```

However, when I run it I get an error because I don't have a firebase json file yet.

> Error: Not in a Firebase app directory (could not locate
> firebase.json)

The question is, How can I deploy a Flutter Web App on a second Firebase Hosting without deleting the previous one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a fair amount of trial and error the solution is as follows:

In the App Root Directory (it's very important):

```
    flutter build web --web-renderer html //In my case, I will 
//generate html web rendered. It will create a firebase.json 
//file and others

    firebase target:apply hosting originalawesome originalawesome
    firebase target: apply hosting secondawesome secondawesome
    //It will create records in .firebaserc file
```

In firebase.json file, you need to include:

```
{
  "hosting": {

    "target": "secondawesome", //deploy target 
//(previously created on Firebase Hosting Console)

    "public": "build/web", //build/web is the directory of the Flutter Web App build
///rest of file
```

Now yes, run...

```
firebase init
```

> ? What do you want to use as your public directory? **build/web**
>
> ? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)?
> **Yes**
>
> ? Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? **No**
>
> ? File build/web/index.html already exists. Overwrite? **No**

To finish and upload the files to the Firebase Hosting ...

```
firebase deploy --only hosting:secondawesome
```

I hope it serves someone else!!